# editing /private/etc/hosts

Tags: ssh, hosts

I just added my no-ip domain to /private/etc/hosts under a shorter alias:

`alias           host.no-ip.biz`

I tried the following on the shell:

`dscacheutil -flushcache`

but it still says:

`ssh: Could not resolve hostname`

What up with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[/etc/hosts can't be used for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/640793):

> /etc/hosts cannot be used (by itself) to produce hostname "aliases".
>
> The hosts file produces the internal equivalent of A and PTR records from the DNS, i.e. mapping of hostname to IP address and vice-versa.
>
> It cannot be used to produce the same effect as a CNAME record.

You can make `ssh alias` equivalent to `ssh host.no-ip.biz` or `ssh username@host.no-ip.biz` by adding lines like this to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host alias
HostName host.no-ip.biz
# User username
```